# CRUD from WordPress to Business Central 365 through OData REST API

Tags: plugins, rest-api, json, web-services, microsoft

The goal here is to use WordPress as a front-end to create, read, update and delete data which is being pulled from Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central through OData Webservices in a JSON format.

How would I get started with this? I've got my Odata V4 URL, Business Central 365 username and password but do not know what's next.

Comment: You're going to need to code everything. WordPress doesn't really have anything that's going to do this for you. You could start with the documentation for the HTTP API, which is a method for making requests within WordPress code: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks!